# Pip install chatterbot

Tags: python

i am having immense difficulty installing chatterbot i receive an error code saying "Failed building wheel for srsly python" and i have no idea how to fix this. I have attempted to find ways to fix this using similar questions i found on SO but no results work.
One solution told me to do a manually pip install spacy but that is where i get before i get an error code with multiple failed to install x, y, z.

I get this each time i try to run the pip install spacy

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
  Complete output (267 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
  Collecting cython<3.0,>=0.25
    Using cached Cython-0.29.24-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (1.6 MB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.5.tar.gz (9.2 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
    Downloading preshed-3.0.5.tar.gz (14 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: still running...
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         cwd: None
    Complete output (82 lines):
    Collecting setuptools
      Using cached setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
    Collecting cython>=0.28
      Using cached Cython-0.29.24-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (1.6 MB)
    Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
      Using cached cymem-2.0.5.tar.gz (9.2 kB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Installing backend dependencies: started
      Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing wheel metadata: started
        Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
    Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
      Using cached murmurhash-1.0.5.tar.gz (12 kB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Installing backend dependencies: started
      Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing wheel metadata: started
        Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
    Building wheels for collected packages: cymem, murmurhash
      Building wheel for cymem (PEP 517): started
      Building wheel for cymem (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
      Complete output (17 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
      package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem\tests
      copying cymem\cymem.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\cymem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
      copying cymem\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
      running build_ext
      building 'cymem.cymem' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cymem
      Building wheel for murmurhash (PEP 517): started
      Building wheel for murmurhash (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
      Complete output (22 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\tests\test_against_mmh3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\tests
      copying murmurhash\mrmr.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\mrmr.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\include
      creating build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\include\murmurhash\MurmurHash2.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
      copying murmurhash\include\murmurhash\MurmurHash3.h -> build\lib.win32-3.9\murmurhash\include\murmurhash
      running build_ext
      building 'murmurhash.mrmr' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for murmurhash
    Failed to build cymem murmurhash
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for cymem, murmurhash which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
    ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/87/cabd3dc3d7ebd9b62252faca25ec5f1fec627ea88ca7ffd2924d02e1516e/preshed-3.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=c6d3dba39ed5059aaf99767017b9568c75b2d0780c3481e204b1daecde00360e (from https://pypi.org/simple/preshed/). Command errored out with exit status 1: ignore-installed --no-user --prefix --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'cython>=0.28' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' Check the logs for full command output.
    Downloading preshed-3.0.4.tar.gz (170 kB)
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
Complete output (56 lines):
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        Complete output (17 lines):
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win32-3.9
        creating build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
        copying cymem\about.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
        copying cymem\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
        package init file 'cymem\tests\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
        creating build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem\tests
        copying cymem\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem\tests
        copying cymem\cymem.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
        copying cymem\cymem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
        copying cymem\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.9\cymem
        running build_ext
        building 'cymem.cymem' extension
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        ----------------------------------------
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for cymem
      ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
      Traceback (most recent call last):
          subprocess.check_call(cmd)
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 

      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 766, in resolve
          dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1051, in best_match
          return self.obtain(req, installer)
packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1063, in obtain
          return installer(requirement)
, line 844, in fetch_build_egg
          return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 77, in fetch_build_egg
          raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
      distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command 
disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', non-zero exit status 1.
      ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/25/73d38655125d46a543656c0f025b3394a2ee010af3d0c46ed75d554bc1a9/preshed-3.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=13a779205d55ce323976ac06df597f9ec2d6f0563ebcf5652176cf4520c7d540 (from https://pypi.org/simple/preshed/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    Downloading preshed-3.0.3.tar.gz (170 kB)
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.5.tar.gz (12 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting thinc<8.1.0,>=8.0.8
    Downloading thinc-8.0.8.tar.gz (166 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: still running...
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
     
    Complete output (73 lines):
    Collecting setuptools
      Using cached setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
    Collecting cython<3.0,>=0.25
      Using cached Cython-0.29.24-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (1.6 MB)
    Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
      Using cached murmurhash-1.0.5.tar.gz (12 kB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Installing backend dependencies: started
      Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing wheel metadata: started
        Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
    Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
      Using cached cymem-2.0.5.tar.gz (9.2 kB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Installing backend dependencies: started
      Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing wheel metadata: started
        Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
    Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
      Using cached preshed-3.0.5.tar.gz (14 kB)
    ERROR: Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
        return func(self, options, args)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
        requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
        result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
        state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
        self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
        if not criterion.candidates:
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
        return bool(self._sequence)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in __bool__
        return any(self)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in <genexpr>
        return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 32, in _iter_built
        candidate = func()
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 204, in _make_candidate_from_link
        self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 295, in __init__
        super().__init__(
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
        self.dist = self._prepare()
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 227, in _prepare
        dist = self._prepare_distribution()
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 305, in _prepare_distribution
        return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 508, in prepare_linked_requirement
        return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 570, in _prepare_linked_requirement
        dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 59, in _get_prepared_distribution
        with req_tracker.track(req):
      File "c:\users\ben\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_tracker.py", line 128, in track
        self.add(req)
      File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-pb8rm6xt\__env_pip__.zip\pip\_internal\req\req_tracker.py", line 97, in add
        raise LookupError(message)
    LookupError: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/87/cabd3dc3d7ebd9b62252faca25ec5f1fec627ea88ca7ffd2924d02e1516e/preshed-3.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=c6d3dba39ed5059aaf99767017b9568c75b2d0780c3481e204b1daecde00360e (from https://pypi.org/simple/preshed/) is already being built: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/87/cabd3dc3d7ebd9b62252faca25ec5f1fec627ea88ca7ffd2924d02e1516e/preshed-3.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=c6d3dba39ed5059aaf99767017b9568c75b2d0780c3481e204b1daecde00360e
    ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/b5/c6fa6b59dae1f007dc7d4270d2c9d275473d6c9c1f092353a2159e54afd0/thinc-8.0.8.tar.gz#sha256=cf2abbd99c56f21b8804f31f995460515d95a5c5988be39e0964469e0070987b (from https://pypi.org/simple/thinc/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 2
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement thinc<8.1.0,>=8.0.8 (from versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.41, 1.42, 1.60, 1.61, 1.62, 1.63, 1.64, 1.65, 1.66, 1.67, 1.68, 1.69, 1.70, 1.71, 1.72, 1.73, 1.74, 1.75, 1.76, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4.1, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.2.0, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.4.0, 6.5.0, 6.5.2, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.7.1, 6.7.2, 6.7.3, 6.8.0, 6.8.1, 6.8.2, 6.9.0, 6.10.0, 6.10.1.dev0, 6.10.1, 6.10.2.dev0, 6.10.2.dev1, 6.10.2, 6.10.3.dev0, 6.10.3.dev1, 6.10.3, 6.10.4.dev0, 6.11.0.dev2, 6.11.1.dev0, 6.11.1.dev1, 6.11.1.dev2, 6.11.1.dev3, 6.11.1.dev4, 6.11.1.dev6, 6.11.1.dev7, 6.11.1.dev10, 6.11.1.dev11, 6.11.1.dev12, 6.11.1.dev13, 6.11.1.dev15, 6.11.1.dev16, 6.11.1.dev17, 6.11.1.dev18, 6.11.1.dev19, 6.11.1.dev20, 6.11.1, 6.11.2.dev0, 6.11.2, 6.11.3.dev1, 6.11.3.dev2, 6.12.0, 6.12.1, 7.0.0.dev0, 7.0.0.dev1, 7.0.0.dev2, 7.0.0.dev3, 7.0.0.dev4, 7.0.0.dev5, 7.0.0.dev6, 7.0.0.dev8, 7.0.0, 7.0.1.dev0, 7.0.1.dev1, 7.0.1.dev2, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.0.4.dev0, 7.0.4, 7.0.5.dev0, 7.0.5, 7.0.6, 7.0.7, 7.0.8, 7.1.0.dev0, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.2.0.dev3, 7.2.0, 7.3.0.dev0, 7.3.0, 7.3.1, 7.4.0.dev0, 7.4.0.dev1, 7.4.0.dev2, 7.4.0, 7.4.1, 7.4.2, 7.4.3, 7.4.4, 7.4.5, 8.0.0.dev0, 8.0.0.dev2, 8.0.0.dev4, 8.0.0a0, 8.0.0a1, 8.0.0a2, 8.0.0a3, 8.0.0a6, 8.0.0a8, 8.0.0a9, 8.0.0a11, 8.0.0a12, 8.0.0a13, 8.0.0a14, 8.0.0a16, 8.0.0a17, 8.0.0a18, 8.0.0a19, 8.0.0a20, 8.0.0a21, 8.0.0a22, 8.0.0a23, 8.0.0a24, 8.0.0a25, 8.0.0a26, 8.0.0a27, 8.0.0a28, 8.0.0a29, 8.0.0a30, 8.0.0a31, 8.0.0a32, 8.0.0a33, 8.0.0a34, 8.0.0a35, 8.0.0a36, 8.0.0a40, 8.0.0a41, 8.0.0a42, 8.0.0a43, 8.0.0a44, 8.0.0rc0, 8.0.0rc1, 8.0.0rc2, 8.0.0rc3, 8.0.0rc4, 8.0.0rc5, 8.0.0rc6.dev0, 8.0.0rc6, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.0.4, 8.0.5, 8.0.6, 8.0.7, 8.0.8)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for thinc<8.1.0,>=8.0.8
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: The error message says: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/". Have you tried doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the other method specified in the official ChatterBot documentation (https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html#installation).

That is, using command line:

1. `git clone https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git`
2. `pip install ./ChatterBot`

Note: I hope you are aware that your Python version must be from 3.4 to 3.8, as newer versions don't seem to be supported.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help but neither of those command lines seemed to work  1)ERROR: Invalid requirement: './ChatterBot' 2)ERROR: Invalid requirement: './ChatterBot'
Thank you for the help